# Cannot compare tensor to scalar anymore in new pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch

I was working with a self compiled version of pytorch 0.4.0 for a while and hence my code has the following line for multidimensional tensors:

```
myTensor3 = torch.arange(torch.numel(myTensor0) # this is a 1 dimensional Tensor
outTensor = myTensor3[(myTensor1 == 1) & (myTensor2 != 1)] # myTensor1 and myTensor2 are multidimensional
```

Whenever I try to switch to another (newer) version of pytorch, the above line throws the following error:

```
IndexError: too many indices for tensor of dimension 1
```

I assume in the newer version of pytorch the index array returned by the comparison operation has dimension 1, whereas before it had the same size as myTensor3.
How can I change back to the old behaviour in the newer version of pytorch?

**Edit:**
A simple fix was to linearize myTensor1 and 2:

```
outTensor = myTensor3[(myTensor1.view(-1) == 1) & (myTensor2.view(-1) != 1)]
```

for some strange reason this was already working in the self compiled pytorch version

Comment: Mh.. I made a short test where indexing is used like you described but I'm getting the same results for pytorch 0.3.1 and 0.4.1, so works for both. Could you provide a complete test case which does work in for you 0.4.0 version and does not work in 0.4.1?

Comment: Ah yes, myTensor3 only has the same size as myTensor1 and 2 but not the same shape. ...